# Convert column headings into row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

This is the data :

```
Calendar years  1990    1991    1992 ...    
Angola          84      71      80   ...
.               .       .       .
.               .       .       .
.               .       .       .
```

Both rows and columns have more data, this is just a sample data

I want the data to look like :

```
Calendar years  Angola  ...
1990            84  
1991            71  
1992            80  
.               .
.               .
.               .
```

I used df.transpose() but it doesn't change the column headings, and instead puts the column headings as 0,1,2..

Any leads will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you could do:

```
df = df.T.reset_index()
df.columns = df.iloc[0, :]
df = df.drop(0)
```

Output:

```
   Calendar years   Angola
1            1990       84
2            1991       71
3            1992       80
```